# Uncaught runtime error while using react form hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I was using React form hook as shown

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
export const Form = () => {
    const {register, handelSubmit} = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Helllo</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handelSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name..." {...register("FullName")}/> <br/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email..." {...register("Email")}/> <br/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Age..." {...register("Age")}/> <br/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." {...register("password")}/> <br/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password..."  {...register("ConfirmPassword")}/> <br/>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};
```

But I got a blank page and there was some uncaught error in the console which I didn't understand.

Error in console:

[image: error in console]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using "handleSubmit" coming from "react-hook-form" ? I think there is a typo somewhere which is causing this issue. If it is the whole code then I think

Comment: Yup. `useForm` returns `handleSubmit` instead of `handelSubmit`